# One-liner to make read-only list of N copies of a reference in Java

Tags: java, list

I have a reference to a `Callable<V>` and I want to put it into a list N times to pass into `ExecutorService.invokeAll(...)`. Is there a one-liner to accomplish this:

```
ArrayList<Callable<V>> list = new ArrayList<>(N);
for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
    list.add(x); // x is a reference to Callable<V>
}
```

Similar to the following line in C++:

```
const std::vector<T> list(N, x); // x is an instance of T
```

Comment: `Collections#fill(List, Object)`?

Comment: What is `x`? The reference to the callable? If yes, you are just creating a list of references to the same `Callable`

Comment: @0xbe5077ed Looks like you want a read-only list. The accepted answer does not explain how to do this. Take a look at my answer which also provides additional details on how you could fall into trouble if you have `n` references to a single `Callable`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
int N = 8;
Callable<Void> a = null;
List<Callable<Void>> nCopies = Collections.nCopies(N, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)), `nCopies()` returns an **immutable** list. If that's fine, it's your best bet.

Alternatively, you can use `Arrays.fill()` to populate an array with the same value, which you can convert into a `List`

```
Arrays.fill(callableArray, x);
List<Callable<V>> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
```